# Adding client id to appengine backend for android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-console

I have created a simple app-engine endpoints api. Now I need to add the `client_id` and `audience` information for the android frontend. Following the links, I ended up at [Configuring Your Web App Backend to Recognize Your Android Client](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android#configuring-your-web-app). But step `2.a` of the instructions does not match anything on the `Google API Console`. After I clicked `API Access`, the only option I get is to `Create an OAuth 2.0 client ID` (so there is no `Create another client ID`). Beyond that point the divergence grows wider. The actual options are `product name`, `Google account`, and `Product logo`. So clearly I am in the wrong tab.

I imagine this is something everyone with an app-engine android app must have gone through. Will someone please help guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions skipped a view steps and renamed a new, but I got there eventually.